# query database using username in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

would it be safe to..

BoughtItems items = GetAllBoughtItemsByUsernameFromDatabase("User.Identity.Name");

and that returns all the items that specific user bought, querying the database using his username.

can the user change the values in the cookies or something like that? What is the best approach to doing that.

In other words it would be like

Select * from tblItems where username = "User.Identity.Name".

Obviously i would use ado or entity..Im using FormsAuthentification.

***So would that be safe?***

Comment: what exactly you want to do? can you please explain to it!!

Answer (score 0):

Each user usually has an id(PK) in the DB.
Now since the username is a unique key, you may prefer fetching the user's id(getIDByUsername) and search the db with an id.

Comment: no i understand but im just asking if it would be safe to do what im doing aka using the User.Identity.Name.

Comment: I dont see something unsafe here. I think that your DB design should not rely on username's but on userid's in this case.